# Can't save recorded video

Tags: swift, video, uiimagepickercontroller, ios10, video-recording

I've got really strange problem and can't solve it.

I'm recording video through the `UIImagePicker`

This is my code of the recording :

```
func takeVideo(_ sender: Any) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [(kUTTypeMovie as NSString) as String]
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.showsCameraControls = true
            //imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = Double(seconds)

            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
            noCamera()
        }
    }
```

And this one is supposed to save the video :

```
    func videoPickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: NSDictionary!) {
        let tempImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL
        let pathString = tempImage?.relativePath
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum((pathString)!, self, nil, nil)

    }
```

My problem is that it lets me to record the video but cant click either of the buttons Retake, Play or Use Video

This is how it looks like after recording video

[image: This is how it looks like after recording video]

Comment: please refer this one i hope it would be helpful for you https://github.com/SanjeetVerma/UIImagePicker-PHAsset-swift/blob/master/PhotoGalleryDemo/ViewController.swift

Comment: Thx tried to do that but nothing changed :/

Comment: It sounds like something is obstructing those buttons. Run your app from Xcode, and when this screen is showing, select **Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy**. You should then be able to see what's preventing you tapping the buttons.

Comment: Ashley Mills i fixed this like year ago but don't think it's supposed to be like that. I tried to use one instance of UIImagePicker for both cases when capturing photo and capturing video. When I created a separated instance for each case it worked fine :)